# Why LoadLibrary loads unrelated DLLs

Tags: dll, loadlibrary, dll-injection

This is about DLL injection.

Let's say P.exe depends on A.dll, B.dll and C.dll (implicit linking), they're private modules of P.exe.

Now I use CreateProcess with CREATE_SUSPENDED flag to launch P.exe, after that I use CreateRemoteThread to call LoadLibrary in target process to load Inject.dll, and in the same way call an initialize function of Inject.dll to do real work (things you can't do in DLLMain).

It works. But I found that calling to LoadLibrary makes A.dll, B.dll and C.dll load too - not just Inject.dll. From the Output of Visual Studio, they even load before Inject.dll, this is not what I want. You know, Inject.dll does not depend on any third-party DLLs, in fact it just depends on kernel32.dll and user32.dll.

In this case, how to load only Inject.dll ?

Comment: I suspect that Windows requires the process to be fully initialized and running for CreateRemoteThread to work. So it may be finishing up loading the executable and dependencies so CreateRemoteThread can work, not so much loading those DLLs as dependencies of the injected DLL.

Comment: Or, alternately, the loader needs to finish the deferred work of resolving the main executable's imports before LoadLibrary can work.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559064/initialize-before-any-global-objects do you have any suggest ?